# How to handle Data Augmentation?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-classification, data-augmentation

I'm building a CNN to perform a binary image classification. However, my dataset is very unbalanced with 10000 images from one class and the oter contains only 3000 (more or less).
That's how my model is looking so far:

```
model_1 = Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 1)),
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, strides=(2,2), padding="same", ),
    layers.Activation(activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])
```

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 rescaling (Rescaling)       (None, 150, 150, 1)       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 75, 75, 16)        160       
                                                                 
 activation (Activation)     (None, 75, 75, 16)        0         
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 37, 37, 16)       0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 21904)             0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 1)                 21905     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 22,065
Trainable params: 22,065
Non-trainable params: 0
```

```
model_1.compile(optimizer="adam",
                loss=tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy,
                metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[These are my results after training for 60 epochs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbWT6.png)

It seems that my model is overfitting, so I tried to use the following data augmentation layers:

```
resize_and_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Resizing(img_height, img_width),
  layers.Rescaling(1./255)
])
data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
  layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
])
```

```
model_1 = Sequential([
    resize_and_rescale,
    data_augmentation,
    layers.Conv2D(16, 3, strides=(2,2), padding="same", ),
    layers.Activation(activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])
```

After training for another 60 epochs, and using the same compile parameters, [that's what I got.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0foC.png)

Apparently, overfit is gone (I guess?), but my curves have these weird edgs which I don't really understand why.

So, should I try implement data augmentation on my dataset instead of adding it to the model?

The task of my model is to identify whether a chest x-ray has COVID or not. I'm using dimensions of 150x150 and grayscale, also, my batch_size is 32.

Comment: Welcome to SO; I am afraid this is not a *programming* question, hence it is actually off-topic here. Please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info for some alternative SE sites where this could be on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the direction of the chest is consistent in the entire dataset. In this situation, vertical flips or rotations are not heplful as augmentation and rather increase noise.